# Fake Windows to think my Bluetooth keyboard is a wired keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, citrix, keylogger

In my work-from-home scenario, I use a Bluetooth Keyboard and Citrix desktop to connect to our corporate infrastructure. Since the last update from our corporate IT, the Citrix client has App Protection enabled and because I use a Bluetooth keyboard, Citrix' anti-keylogging feature kicks in and letters are scrambled every second or so in the Citrix session.

Similar to description found [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Citrix/comments/14j6o7j/external_keyboards_typing_gibberish/) Is there some way to trick Windows to report my Bluetooth keyboard as an USB keyboard?

I don't want to replace my lovely Logitech keyboard.

Comment: If you have administrator privileges, try to stop App Protection by running in an elevated CMD the command `sc stop appprotectionsvc`, or do the same from the Services applet.

Comment: Though you might want to check with IT... If that (obnoxious) service is monitored by them, it could cost your job.